# How do I measure the statistical difference between two measures?

Tags: repeated-measures, standard-deviation, p-value

I am measuring rendering time on Stack Overflow, specifically pre/post changes.

I have data as such

```
pre_post | RouteName      | count | avg | st_dev | min |  max
---------+----------------+-------+-----+--------+-----+-----
1. pre   | Questions/Show | 24736 |  11 |     15 |   0 | 1004
2. post  | Questions/Show |   842 |  16 |     26 |   1 |  453
```

From this I would like to understand:

1. Are the requests statistically slower or faster after the change, or there is no discernible change?
2. How many measurements do I need before having reasonable certainty of point 1.?

---

Here is what the peaks look like (after cleaning, the data is not the same as above!)
[image: nice peaks]

Here is a link to the [raw data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmoPJ_3aTLMMdEg1c00xY1FFaGRJdS1VOWptbW1xY2c&usp=sharing).

---

Here's what the raw data looked like before cleaning and normalizing
[image: twin peaks]

Comment: Sorry if the question is too basic :-)

Comment: Nothing in life is certain, not even in the imaginary modeled realities of statistics. :-)  You *may* ask for an *unreasonable* uncertainty extremely close to $1$, but you will never get to $1$ exactly (unless you are Buzz Lightyear I suppose).

Comment: @whuber Typo! I meant (point) 1.

Comment: Using statistical language requires care.  Not only are there at least two *completely opposite* ways to measure certainty ("confidence," which is large when certainty is good, and "size" which is small when certainty is good), there are two major (but different) representations of it (frequentist confidence intervals and Bayesian credible intervals). Although these niceties don't matter in the present case--provided we are communicating sufficiently clearly--you do need to take care to state what you mean when you use a *number* to represent "certainty."

Comment: The raw data aren't too helpful because they do not contain the information needed to reproduce your cleaning procedure. The results you obtain (using, say, a chi-squared test) will actually be *reversed* after the cleaning: before cleaning there is a shift towards slightly longer times but after cleaning there is a shift towards slightly shorter times.  Both shifts are small but highly (statistically) significant.

Comment: The cleaning was heuristic, I dropped everything below 5ms and above 75ms (this last simply for making the graph look decent). There are two "spurious" points at 22000 which I want to remove because we've had some DB problems which are unrelated. I think that removing the cache hit is also fair because that bit really depends uniquely on the traffic we get, e.g. if a link goes up on reddit, we get a lot of cache hits.

Comment: It looks like the legend on your plots has reversed the `pre` and `post` results.

Comment: I don't think so, the legends look fine - the pre had a lower average because of the cache hits.

Comment: Then the labels in your raw data must be reversed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic questions are good.

In this application you have lots of data and the opportunity to collect many more.  This makes the calculations so easy you can practically do them in your head using fundamental principles.  I will share the standard progression of thinking that a statistician will automatically go through when presented with data like these.

1. The **standard error** (SE) of the "avg" (presumably, arithmetic mean) is the standard deviation divided by the square root of the count.  We may extend the table thus:

   ```
   pre_post | RouteName      | count | avg | st_dev | min |  max |    SE
   ---------+----------------+-------+-----+--------+-----+-------------
   1. pre   | Questions/Show | 24736 |  11 |     15 |   0 | 1004 | 0.095
   2. post  | Questions/Show |   842 |  16 |     26 |   1 |  453 | 0.896
   ```
2. The **standard error of a difference** satisfies the Pythagorean Theorem: it is the root of the sum of squares.  Therefore the difference of averages, $5=16-11$, has a standard error of $$\sqrt{15^2/24736 + 26^2/842} \approx \sqrt{0.095^2+0.896^2} = 0.901.$$

   The form of the general formula (in terms of two averages, two standard deviations, and two counts) should be apparent from this example.
3. **Differences should be measured as multiples of their standard error**, a so-called "Z score."  A "change" is a comparison to $0$, whence the *apparent* amount of change (on average) is

   $$\frac{(16-11) - 0}{\sqrt{15^2/24736 + 26^2/842}} \approx 5.55.$$
4. **$5.55$ standard errors is *big.***  For instance, if rendering times had Normal distributions (they do not), this would give us about $99.99999856$% confidence that the difference is real and not just the result of chance variations in the observations.  (Rounding in the table suggests a more precisely computed Z-score would be somewhere in the $4.5$ to $6.5$ range, but these are large Z-scores regardless and correspond to ridiculously high computed confidences.)
5. However, **these data are not Normally distributed**.  One definite sign of this is that their standard deviations are larger than their averages.  Usually we have to work harder and ask additional questions related to details of the data distribution.
6. Nevertheless, because there are so many `pre` values and a reasonably large number of `post` values, **it's a fair bet that a change has occurred.**  (It would take a lengthy argument to justify this and to put some quantitative bounds on "fair bet," so let's just say this is experience talking.)  A good estimate of the amount of change is the difference $16-11=5$.

---

**Please don't resort to "power calculations" or anything like that:** they could be deceptive due to the (strong) non-Normality of the data.  If you need more detailed insights, then follow up by providing additional information about the data.  Histograms of the `pre` and `post` values would go a long way towards any further analysis.

---

#### Update

**There is no significant difference in *average* times** based on the data that were posted, as "cleaned" to include only durations between 5 and 65 ms: I compute a Z statistic of $0.91$, which is not large at all.  However, there is a difference that is visible in the histograms.  It can be detected with a chi-squared test (which is *extremely* significant, having a p-value essentially zero: the chi-squared statistic is $323$ with $60$ degrees of freedom).  The nature of the difference is clear in the histograms:

[image: Histograms]

The shorter-duration times at 9 and 10 ms appear to have been lengthened (on average) to 12-20 ms.  **A more powerful way to evaluate this change is to plot the standardized chi-squared residuals.**  These are values that, like z-statistics, should usually lie between around $-2$ and $2$ and rarely exceed $3$ in size.  For a given duration, a positive residual for the `post` value means that after the change there were *more* occurrences than expected (assuming no change had occurred) and a negative residual means there were *fewer* occurrences of that duration.  Here is the plot, with lines drawn at $\pm 3$ as a reference:

[image: Residuals]

The evident downward trend (from just significantly positive at 12-14 ms to just significantly negative at 57-64 ms) in the residuals for durations greater than 11 ms suggests the renderings that disappeared from the 8-11 ms group have reappeared scattered throughout the 13-65+ ms range.  This suggests, as a working hypothesis, that **there was a group of short rendering times (comprising 5 to 10% of the total) that were lengthened after the change** but otherwise nothing else seems to have altered.

Comment: I've graphed the timings as you suggessted and discovered two neat peaks (cache hits and cache misses). Since cache hits are not very significant, I've removed them leaving two nice slanted gaussian peaks. I'll update my question with the data and the graph. Thank you.

Comment: That's a nice example of how exploration of data can provide insights that formal statistical tests do not.

Answer (score 0):

To test for changes pre and post within one group you should carry out a repeated-measures ANOVA (repeated-measures T-test). If you want to know how many measurements you would likely need to obtain 1% (.01) certainty you can calculate this doing a statistical power calculator.

I hope that helps!